# connect php pdo on sles apache to mssql database

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, connection, suse

I have got a PHP (v. 5.3.17) Plugin, running on SLES11 Apache, to sent a query to a database. I have installed unixodbc (ver. 2.2.12).

I want to connect the Plugin, via PHP:PDO, to a remote MSSQL Database to run some queries.

PDO:ODBC support is enabled:

```
PDO support enabled 
PDO drivers  odbc, mysql, pgsql, sqlite, sqlite2
```

I tested the connection via Telnet. There I got a positive result.

```
telnet> open 10.22.77.18 1433
Trying 10.22.77.18...
Connected to 10.22.77.18.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I can also connect via tsql to the sql-database:

```
#>tsql -S ms-sql -U <user> -P <passwort>
locale is "LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

Via isql I get the following error:

```
# isql -v  ms-sql
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

I found an instruction on [Connect Linux ODBC with MSsql database](http://www.savelono.com/linux/how-to-configure-linux-odbc-connections-for-ms-sql.html).

When I execute the Skript I got neither the Message "Connection established" nor the message "No connection established". I only get the command prompt ">".
I got this prompt by connecting to a false IP, too.

I think my connection string is wrong, but why do I get no error message?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to MSSQL with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you could use either [SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) or [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

A comment in [the manual for PDO_SQLSRV](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) mentions that Microsoft has not been updating their driver for some time and that official builds only exist for 5.2, 5.3 and 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [SQL Server driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and extract it to your PHP extension directory. Then activate the extension in the `php.ini` file. You need to add the following lines to that file (You need to adapt to your downloaded files names) :

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_52_nts.dll
```

Do not forget to restart the server (It is different from restarting the services). I hope it'll help.

Comment: My Webserver is running on a Linux OS.
I thought DLL´s are only relevant for Windows OS.